# How can I make an on-hover informational tooltip / flyout accessible for a screen reader?

Tags: tooltip, accessibility, screen-readers, flyout

I am working to make an informational tooltip on my company's website accessible (the tooltip currently appears when the link is hovered over or receives keyboard focus), and I can't seem to find any online resources about the best way to make it accessible for a screen reader. It is not a drop-down menu, so using aria-haspopup and aria-expanded won't work. Can anybody who has ever solved this issue share their solution?

Answer (score 2):

The [tooltip widget pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tooltip) is still a work in progress on the W3 site.  I'm not sure how much support there is from screen readers yet on [`role="tooltip"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#tooltip) so it might not work very well.  But the least you can do is associate your tooltip text with the link via the [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby) attribute.  This lets your link have it's normal text and it'll have additional text provided by the destination of `aria-describedby`.  Some screen readers will read the additional text after the link text, and some screen readers will tell you there is additional text and to press a shortcut key to hear the additional text.  So your code would look something like:

```html
<a href="example.com" aria-describedby="mytooltip">you really should read me</a>
...
<div id="mytooltip" role="tooltip">
  more info here
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something very similar, using the role="tooltip" in combination with an aria-label.

Comment: If you have a link with an `aria-label`, the `aria-label` will **override** the visible text of the link which is generally not the desired behavior.  If you have additional text you want read with the link, then `aria-describedby` is a better alternative.  Or you can have visually hidden text embedded in the link that is only "seen" by screen readers.  I can add details on that if interested.